# How can i get BIOS information using java?

Tags: java, bios

Please let me know if i can get the BIOS setting information's using a java program.I am  using windows7 as operating system.

Comment: My advice in one word: don't.  Java is not the tool for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels oooh but it's a contraction of two words...

Comment: @tomfumb: Sorry. I wadn't to gud at gramer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It rather depends on what information you're trying to read.

Java can't read the BIOS, but java can query the WMI (google for jWMI) which might get the data you need.