# Can i change the BIOS setting information using any java program

Tags: java, bios

Please let me know if i can set\change BIOS information setting using java.If possible please give me any hints to do this using java.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052360/how-can-i-get-bios-information-using-java

Comment: @EngFouad: the other post of the OP's was for querying the bios, and this one's for setting it. Why he wants to do this with Java of all the programming languages out there, is beyond me.

Comment: Quite, perhaps op should clarify his intent.

Comment: @user893096: you program, no matter the language it's written in, certainly cannot change any of **my** BIOS, for they're all write-password-protected ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, no. Java is platform independent and not designed to make platform dependant changes like this.